# Android Wear Stacking Notifications maximum

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I am implementing [Stacking Notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html) as documented. But I found that no matter how many Notifications I add to the same group, only the first 12 notifications are shown on the wear (I am using LG Urbane) and the other ignored. I did not found this limit documented anywhere.

- Is there a way to show more notifications ?
- Is this limit fixed or    depends on the watch ?